# Two rods of different proper lengths, questionable condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I was solving problem 3.4 from Rindler's "Relativity - Special, General and Cosmological" (2006), which reads :

> Use a Minkowski diagram to establish the following result: Given two rods of
> rest lengths $l_1$ and $l_2$ ($l_2 < l_1$), moving along a common line with relative velocity
> $v$, there exists a unique inertial frame $S′$ moving along the same line with velocity
> $c^2[l_1 − l_2/ \gamma (v)]/(l_1v)$ relative to the longer rod, in which the two rods have equal lengths, provided $l_1^2(c−v) < l_2^2(c + v)$.

I got the answer just fine, but at no point did I use the provided constraint cited at the very end of the problem. Pondering on it a little, I noticed how it was somehow resemblant to

$$ \left(\frac{l_1}{l_2}\right)^2 < \frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta} = \left(\frac{\lambda_r}{\lambda_s}\right)^2,
$$

where the right hand side of the inequality became the Doppler shift formula for emitted wavelength $\lambda_s$ and received wavelength $\lambda_r$ of some light signal.

Although, I have no idea where it fits in this problem. Is this an errata and is it an unnecessary condition for this solution to exist? Is there a reason for this specification that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $l_1^2(c−v)<l_2^2(c+v)$ is equivalent to the condition that the velocity of $S'$ is less than $c$:

$$\frac{c^2}{l_1 v}[l_1 - \frac{l_2}{\gamma}] < c$$

A little bit of algebra will get you there

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for the explanation. It seems so obvious now that you point it out ...
Thanks a ton again.